# Adding an additional third party dylib causes issues

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dylib

Scenario:
1) I have Xcode project with C++ code and I have added third party dylib (xxxx.dylib) into it. Program runs fine without any issues.
2) Now I add one more dylib into the project named yyyy.dylib. I have just added it and did not use any functionality of it, meaning I just compiled my project once I have added it.
3) Now, one of the third party function call in first dylib (xxxx.dylib) fails because I added yyyy.dylib into the project. Failing here means, the function have some internal exception and I don't have source code to know whats going on. 
4) Now if I remove second dylib (yyyy.dylib) and compile the project again, the function call of xxxx.dylib worked without any errors, thats how I find out that adding second dylib (yyyy.dylib) causing an issue.

Anybody have faced this kind of situation like this? I did not add code here because its all third party lib calls which fails. My guess here is there are some symbol clash between xxxx.dylib and yyyy.dylib internally causing this. Any clue?? Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use the command line program nm to display the symbol table for each dylib and confirm whether or not both libraries are using the same symbols.

Comment: Symbol tables are too big to compare!

Comment: Too big to compare programmatically, surely not? Try the awk command: http://theunixshell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/using-awk-to-only-print-matching-lines.html

Comment: Hmmm.. Thanx.. I compared it and did not find any similar/common symbols between those.

Comment: So that, at least, narrows down the problem.

Comment: Yeah, but still I am wondering why just because adding just a dylib to project, fails the call in other lib..

Comment: Are your dylibs and main program all using the same memory management model, either GC or ARC? If not, I'm wondering if that may be the issue.

Comment: Those dylibs are external and I think one of the dylib is C++ and other one is C.

Comment: It's only guessing here, but maybe it's something to do with flat namespace which, if you're not familiar with, you can read about here: http://glandium.org/blog/?p=2764

Comment: I have read this blog earlier.. and I have confirmed that my second dylib is having flat namespace using this command.. otool -hV yyyy.dylib

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you solve this now, but at least you're more informed. Perhaps you can create another question with the knowledge you've gained and someone else may be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that, I had no other clue other than filing the bug with third party and upgrading to their new lib solved the issue.